# How to get S3 file using android SDK

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am developing a small SDK, and I need to get some files from AWS S3.

Until now I was using a static AWS credentials, as I understood this is very unsecured way to do it, since the Access & Secret Keys are exposed.

I know about AWS Cognito, but I think this is not suitable for an SDK.

Any other way to do it without exposing Access & Secret Key?

Comment: Hi Ovi. Your question needs quite a bit more detail before the community can provide useful answers. For example, one solution to your problem might be "Make all objects in the S3 bucket publicly readable." That might not fit your use case, but there's not enough information in your question to tell. Since StackOverflow is really more for code-related questions and you are asking more of a foundational question, consider starting a discussion on the [Android Mobile AWS SDK Issues page](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/issues).

Comment: Thank, I will do that.